# How to loop through a list payload and insert into database as individual row items in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to insert items in a list in a database as single values in rows with the name of the sender. I am able to send the payload and insert into a single row with the user detailst. How can I loop through the payload sent and insert all the items into individual rows? I have tried to look for examples no luck. So far I can only insert as a single row in the database

this is the payload

```
{"labsigned":["234568","234567","2345678","2344556","12335677","2345677","234556","234545"]}
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/labreport/createrordispatched", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createDispatched(@RequestBody Dispatched dispatched){
    if(labDashboardService.createDispatched(dispatched)) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(true);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(false);
}
```

My Service

```
 public boolean createDispatched(Dispatched dispatched) {


        dispatched.setCreatedBy(getCurrentUserEmail());
        dispatched.setDateCreated(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Dispatched ticket = new Dispatched(
                dispatched.getCreatedBy(),
                dispatched.getDateCreated(),
                dispatched.getlabsigned()
        );

        dispatchedRepository.save(ticket);
        return false;
    }
```

My Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DISPATCHED")
public class Dispatched {
    private String id;
    private String labsigned;
    private Long dateCreated;
    private String createdBy;

    public Dispatched(){}
    public Dispatched(String createdBy, Long dateCreated, String labsigned){
        this.labsigned = rorlabsigned;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;

    }
```

Comment: How do you send that payload?

Comment: Hi @BoussadjraBrahim from a web app, an angular app

Comment: you send only one item ?

Comment: yes from a text area, it has multiple values then I split them and form an array and send to the api. the other times like created by I get the logged in user and date I get current date

Comment: Try to create another controller method then use `saveAll` method in the repository `dispatchedRepository.saveAll(tickets);`

Comment: how will i loop through the data in the list and insert the items in the list on new rows using `dispatchedRepository.saveAll(tickets);` ?

Comment: You should not loop just send the whole array

Comment: And adding the user details and date created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming that you were able to insert all `labsigned` in the payload into one single row with the code you mentioned in the question**, You should iterate `dispatched.labsigned` and insert one by one as rows to accomplish what you need. And returning false at the end of method `createDispatched` will always return `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` even though the records are successfully saved in the DB, so you might need to change it to `return true`.

```
public boolean createDispatched(Dispatched dispatched) {
        List<Dispatched> newTickets = new ArrayList<>();

        dispatched.setCreatedBy(getCurrentUserEmail());
        dispatched.setDateCreated(System.currentTimeMillis());
         
        for(String labSigned:dispatched.getlabsigned()){
            Dispatched ticket = new Dispatched(
                dispatched.getCreatedBy(),
                dispatched.getDateCreated(),
                labSigned
            );
            newTickets.add(ticket);
        }
        dispatchedRepository.saveAll(newTickets);
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi @ThilankaD, thank you, I get an error  `Resolved [java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to edu.umd.model.Dispatched]`

Comment: Hi @arriff, I wonder how the code I have provided can produce an error with `java.util.LinkedHashMap` since that has nothing of Map implementations. the error might be throwing at some other point somewhere else. Could you please check the stack trace of the error or the applications logs and see where the error is thrown from?

Comment: How should I set the `private String labsigned;` on the model? As it also states that `foreach not applicable to type 'java.lang.String'` on this line  `for(String labsigned:dispatched.getlabsigned()){`

Comment: `dispatched.getRorlabsigned()` so do you have another field called `Rorlabsigned` inside `Dispatched` model class?

Comment: this is the correct bit `dispatched.getlabsigned()` this is the field called `labsigned` inside `Dispatched` model class

Answer (score 0):

Just send in a list of those values. Shouldn't have to be wrapped in a named field on an object. Just send it in as a json array like ["234568","234567","2345678","2344556","12335677","2345677","234556","234545"]. In your controller method, body don't pass it in as Dispatched but instead a List and then just loop through those creating a list of Dispatch objects and then using saveAll in the repository passing in the newly created Dispatched list.

Update: Example without actually compiling. Should be good enough for the example. Also using lombok to make it easier to read and a few other updates.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
@RestController
public class DispatchController {
    
    DispatchedEntityFactory dispatchedEntityFactory;
    DispatchedRepository dispatchedRepository;
    
    @PostMapping("/labreport/createrordispatched")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> createDispatched(DispatchedRequest dispatchedRequests){
        List<DispatchedEntity> dispatchedEntities = dispatchedEntityFactory.creatMultipleFromDispatchRequest(dispatchedRequests);
        
        if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(dispatchedEntities)) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(false);
        }
        
        dispatchedRepository.saveAll(dispatchedEntities);
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
    }

}
```

```
@Value
public class DispatchedRequest {

    String id;
    List<String>labsigned;
    Long dateCreated;
    String createdBy;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DISPATCHED")
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class DispatchedEntity {
    String id;
    String labsigned;
    Long dateCreated;
    String createdBy;
}
```

```
@Component
public class DispatchedEntityFactory {

    public List<DispatchedEntity> creatMultipleFromDispatchRequest(final DispatchedRequest dispatchedRequest) {
        List<DispatchedEntity> dispatchedEntities = new ArrayList<DispatchedEntity>();
        
        for(String labsignature : dispatchedRequest.getLabsigned()) {
            DispatchedEntity dispatchedEntity = new DispatchedEntity(dispatchedRequest.getId(),labsignature, dispatchedRequest.getDateCreated(), dispatchedRequest.getCreatedBy());
            dispatchedEntities.add(dispatchedEntity);
        }
        
        return dispatchedEntities;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Heyo, and what happens to adding the name of the person who send the file and the date, when are those going to be inserted?

Comment: Hello @arriff. How much data are you sending as part of the payload? If you are going to send all the data every time then take in a list of Dispatched objects. You will have to form your object correctly to align with the json you are passing in to do it this way. Currently you just have a Json object that contains an array of strings where according to Dispatched class, you are just expecting an object with no arrays. You can create a serializer to do it but it would just be easier to match your Json and Java Object if possible.

Comment: If you can't match the entity object with the json then have a presentation layer object, the java object that matches the json, and then create the entity object from the presentation layer object and insert the newly created entity into your database,

Comment: Can you show me an example that will be more than help full

Comment: I updated with an example @arriff. Also sorry for the late response.